# Graph coefficient

Tags: graph-theory

Can someone please explain to me how do you calculate this graph coefficient clustering?

Using igraph to calculate it, the result is 0.6.

[image]

What I don't understand is the mathematical formula behind this calculus. I know clustering coefficient=(3*number of triangles)/number of triplets, but i don't get it how with this formula you can reach the result 0.6.

Comment: You got an explanation of the formula [once](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4311790/graph-coefficient-clustering/4311798#4311798) already, what you're doing now is just making people do your homework for you.

Comment: Actually the other explanation i got left me without understanding the formula anyway

Comment: If you do not understand an explanation, you can ask for clarification. Deleting your question immediately is pretty much the rudest thing you can do on Math StackExchange, and also makes me suspect that you're cheating on an assignment and trying to hide it.

Answer (score 1):

The notion of a triplet is often defined informally, which leads to this ambiguity in interpretation.  A triplet is obtained by taking a vertex $u$ and two of its neighbors $v, w$.  The number of triplets is the number of ways to choose $u$, and then to choose $v, w$.

For such a choice of $u, v, w$, they could either form a triangle, or a path with three vertices without a shortcut, which we will call a $P_3$.  If $u, v, w$ form a triangle, then that triangle will be enumerated three times, one for each choice of center.  However, each $P_3$ will only be enumerated once.

Therefore, the number of triplets is ($3 \times $ number of triangles) + (number of $P_3$).
You can see that there are $2$ triangles, and that the number of $P_3$s in your graph is $4$ (namely, $153, 154, 253, 254$).  Thus, the number of triplets is $6 + 4 = 10$.  Hence, the coefficient is $6/10 = 0.6$.